# How to protect my image and file folder from direct access using url in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Please help me to avoid direct access when we enter the path to file/image..

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: you can validate a file to download only when someone is login to your website.

Comment: user can download  only when they signin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596116/caching-http-responses-when-they-are-dynamically-created-by-php/10596231#10596231

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your image outside web folder and serve it with php.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Directory listing** to **false** for the folder you want to protect from direct access.
In your hosting panel there is a option to set this Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel, use "**Hotlink Protection**". Hotlink protection prevents other websites from directly linking to files on your website. You can block direct access by specifying  extensions. You can add jpg, png, gif,etc. for this problem.

Here is the [tutorial](https://www.cpanel.net/media/tutorials/hotlink_lo.htm).

https://www.cpanel.net/media/tutorials/hotlink_lo.htm