# How to speed up file_get_contents?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Here's my code:

```
$language = $_GET['soundtype'];
$word = $_GET['sound'];
$word = urlencode($word);
if ($language == 'english') {
    $url = "<the first url>";
} else if ($language == 'chinese') {
    $url = "<the second url>";
}
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: <my user agent>"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$page = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
echo $page;
```

But I've found that this runs terribly slow.

Are there any possible methods of optimization?

**Note:** `$url` is a remote url.

Comment: is $url a local path or a http:// url ?

Comment: @Intrepidd Yes, sorry about that, a remote url.

Comment: What's the size of the file and many seconds does it take to fetch? Divide one by the other and you'll find the bandwidth. If it's unexpectedly slow, either you or the remote side needs more!

Comment: Define "slow".  Two seconds?  Twenty seconds?  Two minutes?  What are you using to measure?  What are you comparing it against?  Is it also slow at the command line?  How about other methods, like curl?  What have you done to test and troubleshoot?

Comment: Then why don't you just downloas the two files to your server and serve these files instead of the remote ones ?

Comment: @Intrepidd because they keep on changing, the two files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's slow because `file_get_contents()` reads the entire file into `$page`, PHP waits for the file to be received before outputting the content. So what you're doing is: downloading the entire file on the server side, then outputting it as a single huge string.

`file_get_contents()` does not support streaming or grabbing offsets of the remote file. An option is to create a raw socket with [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), do the HTTP request, and read the response in a loop, as you read each chunk, output it to the browser. This will be faster because the file will be streamed.

Example from the Manual:

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {

    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The above is looping while there is still content available, on each iteration it reads 128 bytes and then outputs it to the browser. The same principle will work for what you're doing. You'll need to make sure that you don't output the response HTTP headers which will be the first few lines, because since you are doing a raw request, you will get the raw response with headers included. If you output the response headers you will end up with a corrupt file.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? `fsockopen()` is Greek to me.

Comment: Please, please, *please* don't write *yet another* socket-based HTTP client.  There are at least two PHP native ways to make HTTP requests and *dozens* of high-quality, well-tested pure-PHP HTTP libraries out there that can do all the things you need and more.

Comment: @Charles, I don't intend to write a HTTP client. The question is why is the current code slow or how to speed it up, and the example code is used to illustrate exactly that.  Of course you can use any HTTP library you can find but it must support streaming (not all do). There are many ways to skin a cat and the point I'm trying to make in this answer is that streaming is the solution.

Comment: -1. Your code is basically stream_copy_to_stream() but less efficient.

Comment: @Jack how is it less efficient? I don't claim this is my code, as pointed out in the answer it's copied from the manual and used to illustrate that streaming will greatly increase performance. The different methods of streaming or the HTTP library employed will be micro-optimisation.

Comment: Even if the loop is almost as efficient than PHP's internal code, a) it's not binary safe and b) it can be written in just three lines of code.

Comment: That is micro-optimisation, OP can do as much of that as he wants to shave a few nanoseconds but the point of this question is to address what is actually slow. Also less lines != better always.

Comment: Binary safety is not micro-optimisation! At least change to fread() instead of fgets().

Comment: fgets() is binary safe, what makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Because fgets() reads to the next newline, skipping all characters after having read 128 bytes.

Comment: Let's put it another way; for example, a text document with each line longer than 128 bytes. Your current answer would chop off the last remainder bytes of each line. The results are worse for binary files.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of downloading the whole file before outputting it, consider streaming it out like this:

```
$in = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
$out = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

header('Content-Type: video/mpeg');
stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out);
```

If you're daring, you could even try (but that's definitely experimental):

```
header('Content-Type: video/mpeg');
copy($url, 'php://output');
```

Another option is using internal redirects and making your web server proxy the request for you. That would free up PHP to do something else. See also [my post regarding X-Sendfile and friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596116/caching-http-responses-when-they-are-dynamically-created-by-php/10596231#10596231).

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @MrCode, first downloading the file to your server, then passing it on to the client will of course incur a doubled download time. If you want to pass the file on to the client directly, use [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile).

Alternatively, think about if you can't simply *redirect the client* to the file URL using a `header("Location: $url")` so the client can get the file directly from the source.

Comment: can you change the User Agent of the request when using `readfile`?

Comment: It also supports a `$context` resource, so yes.